# Angular defining parameters twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, controller

Consider the examples below. Do they work differently?

```
.controller('MyController',function($scope) {
  $scope.username = 'World';

  $scope.sayHello = function() {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hello ' + $scope.username + '!';
  };
});
```

Vs

```
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.username = 'World';

  $scope.sayHello = function() {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hello ' + $scope.username + '!';
  };
}]);
```

They output the same for me, I just don't get why we put it there. Sometimes I have to put it as object to work. Why defining it twice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thats an interesting question. Answer is both the things work as expected in local environment. But..

> Array notation is useful when you Minify/obfuscate JavaScript files for production release. In that case the argument $scope might be renamed to $s, but because we defined string ‘$scope’ as first argument, Angular is aware that first dependency to this controller is $scope object.

So until and unless you are writing something which is for internal purpose, use array notation which is recommended! :)

Refer this: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-controller-tutorial/

Comment: Plus, using array notation improves testability.